# Can we call one .sql file from another in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana

I want to know, can we call  one .sql file from another .sql file in SAP HANA? If yes, then please tell me how?

Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using stored procedures? One procedure can call other stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation (SAP HANA Administration Guide) :

```
 \i[nput] <file> Imports commands from the batch file <file>
```

Comment: Anything other than that

Comment: Well that's the feature for that - so, no, there is nothing 'other' than that.